Values from codebase and classid in object tag is not rendering
Details:
ASP.NET application(aspx, VB)
I am trying to load an image from a URL by using the CODEBASE and CLASSID attributes of an html tag. I am unable to render it.
But the one with data attribute loads
Providing below details of my code in aspx page
<body>
     <h2>Test</h2>
     <h4>Object tag with data</h4>
  <object data="https://media.licdn.com/dms/image/C560BAQEQWtChAJoVMg/company-logo_200_200/0/1648854948600?e=2147483647&v=beta&t=uZcV3mbaKjPyWcCnnsBcuwlE-dUwH9tVz60UztCM83g"></object>
     <h4>Object tag with codebase</h4>
  <object
    CLASSID="clsid:image.png"
    CODEBASE="https://somewebsite.com/Foldername/"
  ></object>
</body>


For the CODEBASE attribute I have given the URL until the folder.
For CLASSID, I have given name of image that needs to be rendered.

I am not sure why I am unable to render it.
Also If there is any resource that I can refer to understand please do share.

It is not at all clear why you using a "object" here?
If you want to display a image, then a good choice is a image control.
If I drop in a image control, and set it to your sample URL, say like this:
        <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server"
            ImageUrl="https://media.licdn.com/dms/image/C560BAQEQWtChAJoVMg/company-logo_200_200/0/1648854948600?e=2147483647&v=beta&t=uZcV3mbaKjPyWcCnnsBcuwlE-dUwH9tVz60UztCM83g"                
            />

Then the result is this:

So, if you looking to have a image in your markup?
Then using a image control makes the most sense here.
I see no samples, no logic, or nothing in web land that hints, suggests, or implies that using a "object" element makes any kind of a logical choice here when attempting to display a image.
If you want to display a image, then use a image control.
Edit: display different image if URL is broken
So, in comments, the question has now become:
I want to change the image if the URL is broken.
Once again, using object does not help this goal, and should NOT be used here. Again: Why use object element when it is of no use to solve your problem. You keep comming back and asking how to use object to solve this problem?
Answer: using object does not help, should not be used, and will not solve your problem.
So, state what your goal is, not out of the blue hope on a wing and prayer that "object" will help solve your problem when use of object is not going to help you solve your problem!
So,  you can't ask how to use "object" and it's settings to help you solve your problem when using "object" is the wrong approach here, and will not help you. You can't solve your question and problem by using object, so do not try to use object element to solve your problem, since it not going to solve your problem.
It is possbile you are attempting to do somthing else, but so far, with your follow up in comments, the queston has now become:
I want to change or subsitple the an image for URL's that are broken.
Ok, then taking our above image control, we can add this to the markup:
    <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server"
        ImageUrl="https://media.licdn.com/dms/image/C560BAQEQWtChAJoVMg/company-logo_200_200/0/1648854948600?e=2147483647&v=beta&t=uZcV3mbaKjPyWcCnnsBcuwlE-dUwH9tVz60UztCM83g"
        onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src='/Content/generics.png'"
        />

So, in above, the URL is valid, but let's modify the URL to be broken, say like this:

So, in above, for testing, I now have a broken (invalid) URL for the image, and thus image control will now display the image I have specified in the onerror event for the image control (this is client side JavaScript).
Hence, the result is now this:

So, once again, we conclude that using "object" is the wrong approach, will not solve our problem, and does not give rise to your desired solution.
So, the REAL solution here is to dump the use of the "object" tag, since all the questions in the world about some object tag will not help you, and will not solve your goal (which I assume now is to specify a alternative image for broken URL's).
Hint:
If you wanting to display a image, use a image control and not the object tag, since use of the object tag will not solve your problem, and is of no help in your desired outcome.

Actually the intent of me using object is bcz I wanted to check if url specified inside codebase attribute is blocked my CSP header or not. I was trying with simple image load.
Could you please help me know in detail about cobebase and classid attribute of object tag. It would be helpful if you could provide code example where I can get clear idea of how cobebase and classid attribute values render for object tag

See my new edit as to how you can replace a broken image with a alternative image. As noted, using object tag will not help you, and is the wrong approach, so you have to dump use of the object tag, since it is the wrong approach and wrong answer and wrong way to find a solution to your goal here.
